# Is it possible to have different controllers for each stomp endpoint in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

Is it possible to assign different Controller or at least a different MessageMapping for each of the stomp endpoints?
My goal is to have client1 connecting to /endpoint1 and client2 connecting to /endpoint2 without client1 being able to access any topics/queues of /endpoint2 and vice-versa (they are completely different applications).
So they would be completely encapsulated implementations based on the endpoint to which they connect.

Bonus points for being able to use different Jackson ObjectMapper for each endpoint as well.

So far I have created a websocket configuration with 2 endpoints (/endpoint1 and /endpoint2):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint1", "/endpoint2")
              .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
              .withSockJS();
   }

   // etc...

}
```

I also have a Controller which can process requests and send them to appropriate user response queue, but it's accessible from both endpoints:

```java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
   @MessageMapping("/request")
   @SendToUser("/queue/response")
   public MyResponse handleMessage(MyRequest request) {
      // implementation
   }
}
```

**Current behaviour:**
It doesn't matter which endpoint is my client connecting to in my current implementation, both can access the same topics, which is unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alter your application design so that clients would be only able to send messages to their respective *STOMP* destinations. You can name your *STOMP* destinations in a client-specific prefixed way such as:

```
/endpoint1/request
/endpoint2/request
```

You should then be able to define different `@MessageMapping`-annotated message handlers after the above naming pattern:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/endpoint1/request")
    @SendToUser("/endpoint1/queue/response")
    public MyResponse handleClient1Message(MyRequest request) {
      // process STOMP message from client 1
    }

    @MessageMapping("/endpoint2/request")
    @SendToUser("/endpoint2/queue/response")
    public MyResponse handleClient2Message(MyRequest request) {
      // process STOMP message from client 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this was the only way.
It solves the problem with different request/response structures and handlers, but I'd have to implement other security measures if one of the client applications was implemented externally for example. 

If endpoint dictated visible/available topics, then it would be as simple as - let's say - allowing external connections to access only one of the endpoints with nginx or similar.

Thanks for the reply nonetheless, much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, your use case won't be supported through STOMP on top of WebSockets as the latter would only offer a single endpoint to relay connections to the backend (at least when on top of Spring framework). You can still leverage `WebSocketSecurityConfig` bean to encode your security rules preventing any client(1/2) to access the disallowed destination (or queue) https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#_custom_authorization